# Places api set location biased based on current location

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am using the the new `AutocompleteSupportFragment` so user can search for places and choose the one he is interested in. I want to prefer the results to be around the user. I understand that the I can set `LocationBias` however it takes `RectangularBounds`.

I don't know what the rectangular bounds will be as I only have the current  location `LatLng`. How can I achieve the desired behavior?

Thank you

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926743/android-places-autocomplete-set-lat-long-bounds

Comment: Awsome. Yes that's what I am looking for . link it an answer and I will accept it

Comment: I have added it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set latlong bounds based on users current location. Below is an example for the same.

```
private void setBounds(Location location, int mDistanceInMeters ){
    double latRadian = Math.toRadians(location.getLatitude());

    double degLatKm = 110.574235;
    double degLongKm = 110.572833 * Math.cos(latRadian);
    double deltaLat = mDistanceInMeters / 1000.0 / degLatKm;
    double deltaLong = mDistanceInMeters / 1000.0 / degLongKm;

    double minLat = location.getLatitude() - deltaLat;
    double minLong = location.getLongitude() - deltaLong;
    double maxLat = location.getLatitude() + deltaLat;
    double maxLong = location.getLongitude() + deltaLong;

    Log.d(TAG,"Min: "+Double.toString(minLat)+","+Double.toString(minLong));
    Log.d(TAG,"Max: "+Double.toString(maxLat)+","+Double.toString(maxLong));

    // Set up the adapter that will retrieve suggestions from the Places Geo Data API that cover
    // the entire world.
    mAdapter = new PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            mGoogleApiClient, new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(minLat, minLong), new LatLng(maxLat, maxLong)), null);
    mAutocompleteView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

For further reference you can follow the below link

[Set Bounds for Places Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926743/android-places-autocomplete-set-lat-long-bounds)